# DOM Element reference is null - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

I'm working on a flexible menu, that does not need to jump from page to page when clicking 'links'.
The JavaScript I use for that is as follows:

```
var inbox = document.getElementById("u-content-inbox");
var friends = document.getElementById("u-content-friends");
var agenda = document.getElementById("u-content-agenda");
var list = document.getElementById("u-content-list");
var news = document.getElementById("u-content-news");
var notes = document.getElementById("u-content-notes");

function Inbox() {
  inbox.style.visibility='visible';
}

function Friends() {
  friends.style.visibility='visible';
}

function Agenda() {
  agenda.style.visibility='visible';
}

function List() {
  list.style.visibility='visible';
}

function News() {
  news.style.visibility='visible';
}

function Notes() {
  notes.style.visibility='visible';
}
```

The div elements are like this:

```
<div id="u-content-inbox" style="visibility:hidden;">
  Inbox
</div>

<div id="u-content-friends" style="visibility:hidden;">
  Friends
</div>
```

Each div has a "u-content-x".
However, when I try to change the style attribute "visibility" to visible. It gives me the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`

I'm not seeing what I'm doing wrong. Could somebody please bring clearance to me why exactly JavaScript, or rather, I fail to make it work?
Whenever I run a check on

```
if(!inbox) {
alert("Inbox div has not been found);
}
```

does not show the alert message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you call your javascript after the document is loaded! I'm nearly certain you are trying to get element references before they exist in the dom. The best practices is to put all scripts just before the closing of the body tag.

```
  <script src="some/path/to/file.js"></script>
</body>
```

If your scripts appear in the document before the elements do, you can put your code inside of this load event function:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
 //your code here
});
```

Just as a note on your code architecture, you could attach a class to each element and then do this:

```
var toMakeVisible = document.getElementsByClassName('some-class');
for (var i=0; i<toMakeVisible; ++i) {
  var elem = toMakeVisible[i];
  elem.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! I'll have to wait for 10 minutes to accept your answer, though.

Comment: @JesseDijkstra great, thanks! See my update for a suggestion on improving your code. Keep your code DRY! (don't repeat yourself).

Comment: I also need the others to disappear again, after the user has clicked on a new 'link' in the menu. I might use a switchState(newState) function, though I have to see how I can concatenate the prefix "u-content-x" with the x. To keep the code as small as possible..

Comment: Still new to JavaScript and DOM, though I'm learning quickly.