# ThreeJS Cannot set domElement of WebGLRenderer

Tags: javascript, three.js, babeljs, browserify

While building a ThreeJS project I encounter this error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'domElement' of undefined**

The file before converting to normal js for browsers is:

*index.js*

```js
import { Scene, WebGLRenderer} from 'three';
import { THREEGLTFLoader } from 'three-loaders';

var scene = new Scene();
var loader = new THREEGLTFLoader();
var renderer = WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
loader.load(
    "/models/cube.glb",
    function (gltf) {
        scene.add(boat)
    }
);
```

*index.html*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></meta>
        <title>ThreeJS WebGLRenderer</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="height: 100%; width:100%">
            <noscript>
                The page cannot be loaded because javascript is disabled...
            </noscript>
            <canvas id="container"></canvas>
        </div>
        <script src="build.js" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm using babel and browserify to convert the file.

**solution:**
I solved the problem switching to webpack, and it actually works

Comment: in your script tag why "async defer" together. remove "async", and scripts are "defer" by default.

Comment: I followed you tip but the error still here, anyway thanks for the tip

Comment: Feels like your script is executing before your document is loaded. Also, are you grabbing some dom element? somewhere inside your code. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223575/dom-element-reference-is-null-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-style

Comment: I run the code using the Chrome debugger, it tells me that domElement is defined (It's a canvas element), while is not defined this. (The line that gives the error is: this.domElement = canvas;)

Comment: Could you please share this code snippet also here?

Answer (score 1):

> import { Scene, WebGLRenderera} from 'three';

You have a typo in your code. It should be:

```
import { Scene, WebGLRenderer } from 'three';
```

Besides, please don't use the `three-loaders` npm package. You can import `GLTFLoader` like all other example files from the `three` npm package like so:

```
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
```